# A simple description of $ {C^{*}}(\Gamma) \otimes_{\sigma} {C^{*}}(\Gamma) $ when $ \Gamma $ is finite.

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> **Problem.** Let $ \Gamma $ be a discrete group. Denote its full group $ C^{*} $-algebra by $ {C^{*}}(\Gamma) $. If $ \Gamma $ is a finite group, then is it true that $ {C^{*}}(\Gamma) \odot {C^{*}}(\Gamma) = {C^{*}}(\Gamma) \otimes_{\sigma} {C^{*}}(\Gamma) $?

**Notation:**

- If $ A $ and $ B $ are $ C^{*} $-algebras, then $ A \otimes_{\sigma} B $ denotes their spatial tensor product, which is defined as the completion of the algebraic tensor product $ A \odot B $ with respect to the spatial norm $ \| \cdot \|_{\sigma} $.
- $ {C^{*}}(\Gamma) $ is the completion of $ \mathbb{C}[\Gamma] $ with respect to the norm
  $$
  \| f \|
  \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
  \sup \!
  \left( \left\{
  \| \pi(f) \|_{\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})} ~ \Big| ~
  \text{
  $ (\pi,\mathcal{H}) $ is a non-degenerate $ * $-representation of $ \mathbb{C}[\Gamma] $
  }
  \right\} \right).
  $$
- $ \mathbb{C}[\Gamma] $ denotes the group ring of $ \Gamma $, i.e., the ring of all finitely supported functions $ f: \Gamma \to \mathbb{C} $, where the sum of two functions is defined component-wise and the product of two functions is their convolution. (**Note:** If $ \Gamma $ is already finite, then every function $ f: \Gamma \to \mathbb{C} $ is automatically finitely supported.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Gamma$ is finite then the group ring is finite-dimensional,  and so it is already closed.  Thus $C^*(\Gamma) $ is finite-dimensional. The same happens with the algebraic tensor product: it is finite-dimensional,  so closed.

Comment: I wonder where did @Martin Argerami get the word “closed” (do not see it in the original post). A normed vector space (such as the algebraic tensor product) is, of course, “closed” in the sense that any topological space is closed in itself. But a normed vector space is not necessarily *complete*.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: all finite-dimensional normed vector spaces are complete.  That's what this question is about.